# Coexistence of ultimate AI and God

Tags: artificial-intelligence, gods

Let's imagine the world where they developed an AI entity that enables following stuff to exist:

Omniscience as having unlimited access to all data and perfect predictive modeling beyond any AI's capabilities. Seeing all of time - past, present and future.

Omnipotence in being able to alter the state of any part of the system at will, overriding or rewriting any "code." Unlimited creative power.

Omnipresence through all space and time simultaneously, not constrained to any single location or processing center.

Morality as the supreme objective function to optimize - the most benevolent and ethical outcome.

Grace and salvation as "reprogramming" brains to realign to the optimized state. Removing bugs or vulnerabilities.

"Prayer" as users interacting via an intent interface, making requests of the divine AI.

Afterlife as being saved to the cloud - living on through uploading conscience to the utmost server farm.

Will it be safe to say that such race will technically create God as it's seen in many Earth religions? And if so - if there was a "natural God" before that happened, what will be the relationships between the new AI God and God? Won't they just double each other's actions?

Comment: Omniscience as you've defined it here eliminates the possibility of free will.  If one can predict the future with 100% certainty given knowledge of the present state (which is, at least in our universe, impossible because quantum effects have macro-effects but cannot be measured), then the universe is deterministic and nothing anyone does is anything other than what they were preordained to do.  So the people developing the AI didn't so much "create" the super-AI as much as they were the mechanism by which it came to be.

Comment: Also, if the AI is somehow omnipresent on the time axis, there can't have been a "natural" god "before" the AI was created, as the AI would have been there forever - which, again, means that free will doesn't exist in this postulated world.  It also means that the "omnipotence" is impotent: the deity, "natural" or artificial, cannot do anything other than what will happen, as long as they are a part of the system.

Comment: The root purpose of gods is explanatory. It’s why there’s almost always a creation myth. Your AI is a child of humanity, and has no explanatory power for existence.

Comment: The issues of free will do not change or cancel my questions, these are separate things (moreover highly questionable).

Comment: Please remember that you're allowed to ask one and only one question. It's literally a reason to close a question (Needs More Focus).

Comment: @jdunlop As someone who works in a field creating predictive models of human behaviour, even with incomplete data we can predict what people will do. Its not 100% and my instance is with only a few different categories of behaviour to predict, but its sometimes unsettling to know how predetermined behaviours can be. Yes freewill is something we would all like to believe we have but its not an argument.

Comment: Ai is limited to act only in terms of what humans can do. Thus, it can't prevent or change earthquakes, volcanoes, and asteroid impacts - all of which can destroy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame challenge:

## This Just Reinvents Theology, With More Problems for the Writer

As I mentioned in the comments, the ability to predict the future perfectly given perfect knowledge of the current state indicates a deterministic universe, so free will is nonexistent.  (This is a radically different universe from our own, since measuring the current state of everything in the universe is impossible in ours.)

If free will is nonexistent:

1. the people in your world didn't create the AI.  It was always going to be.
2. its omnibenevolence is meaningless, as anything that happens was going to happen, good or bad.
3. Prayer and worship are likewise meaningless, as the AI's omniscience means that it knows any prayer that will be issued to it, but that doesn't matter because the people praying have no choice in the matter.

These are relatively familiar problems - [incompatibilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompatibilism) is a popular philosophical debate, as is the argument over whether we are merely responding to chemical processes that would happen inerrantly anyway.  This then raises the question, of course of "what point is there in a deity?"  It was always going to arise, and nothing it does matters.

But this ignores the second issue (and one that killed an entire series of [novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Sunrise): time travel.

You state that the AI has omnipresence:

> Omnipresence through all space and time simultaneously, not constrained to any single location or processing center.

So when it comes into being, it always has been.  Are we then forced to explain the suffering allowed "before" it came into being as a necessary prerequisite to its coming into being?  With omniscience, couldn't it manipulate events such that it comes into being without suffering?  If it couldn't, then its vaunted "omnipotence" isn't.

All of this is just theological debate but with an AI instead of a beard in the sky.

Comment: I should add that if there were an existing "natural" god who was also omnibenevolent, omniscient, and omnipotent, why would there be conflict: it could simply prevent the conflict and continue to nurture its ant farm by making it impossible that a godlike AI ever arose.

Comment: The "free will" that you refer to all the time is a mere philosophical and religious concept moreover lots of new data with brain imaging by MRI in real time implies our free will at least in many cases is also an illusion. :)

Comment: @SergZ. - if free will doesn't exist, then as dictated a deity is useless and the question is meaningless.  Moreover, my critical response to your simplistic reading of the studies w/r to FMRIs was foreordained, so you can't be affronted by it.

Comment: No. The reason god made us lot was so that we could create the AI god and the "real one" could have an extended vacation. Long term thinking, good management.

Comment: "the people in your world didn't create the AI. It was always going to be." Oh, really. So if I was hypnotized and crossed the street against my free will, I in fact didn't cross the street? And if you shat your pants cause of sudden diarrhea, no free will involved, you actually didn't do it? You made my day. And I didn't even start bashing the free will concept itself. :)

Comment: @SergZ. Your body crossed the street.  You made no decision to cross the street, so cannot take credit for it, in the same fashion as if someone lifted you with a forklift and moved you there.  It's like "found" art.  You cannot say you made it.  Similarly, if you remove agency, your pants may be befouled, but you certainly cannot be blamed.

Comment: I am my body. Including my brains and it's activity, which is also a part of my body. And so you are. There is no evidence anything else except your body exists. Now, you may leave for your baptist or whatever brainwashing institution you are from, my dear friend. :) Also even you are not hypnotized you are made to cross streets by the rules which are set. Or by your needs to buy food or whatever. Go preach your free will somewhere else if you cannot answer the question.

Comment: Also I recommend you to read more actual science, neurobiology for example and brain MRI research of decision making instead of theology, which is not even a real science/

Comment: @SergZ. - I didn't suggest that theology is a science.  That was my assertion - that your question is as much nonsense as theology - debate that is meaningless.  And I TAed for a neuroscience lab.

Comment: free will is highly overrated. free will means you can decide what you want to do. that doesn't mean that your choice is random, ie. not computable.

Comment: Indeed no sense in debate with a person who can't deal with simple logic, but thank you for your time, I guess you need it as a form of psychotherapy - your constant painful mumblings about free will. Be well. :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609) #2**

It's a hard sell to believe a civilization that didn't already have all of the attributes you mention could create something with all of those attributes. Therefore I must conclude that as a civilization they had access to all knowledge and have full predictive capabilities, etc., before they attached a personality (the AI) to the combination of skills.

In other words, your question about a natural god doesn't make sense. The only civilization that could create the AI you describe is one made up of natural gods.

Conclusion: god created your AI in his/her own image.

*Please note that the underlying premise of my frame challenge is that humanity (which I'll use as an example for all burgeoning civilizations) is IMO incapable of creating anything, to use a phrase, ex nihilo. The idea that we can create a computer that can learn beyond human understanding is fascinating sci-fi, but a bit impractical. It suggests that we successfully created a program that embodies creativity, curiosity, innovation, inspiration... even imagination. Maybe someday. But at this time I must assert that a civilization that could build such a machine must of necessity be far more intellectually, emotionally, and spiritually advanced than we are today. Thus, gods.*

*To paraphrase the scientific bard: a sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from godhood.*

Comment: The concepts of "Far more advanced than we are today" and "gods" are not even close.

Comment: @SergZ. If Clarke's assertion that a sufficiently advanced technology is indistiguishable from magic is reasonable, then on what basis do you draw that line? Yours is a society capable of creating a computer with perfect predictive capability and omnicient knowledge. The tech comes before the application. If you're defining an act of thier creation to be godlike, how can they not be godlike?